# Using FormData on IE9/Angular 5/TypeScript without Ajax nor jQuery

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, form-data

In my application [Angular 5](https://angular.io/)/[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), I have an `UploadFile` component looks like :

*`component.html`*

```
....
<form #formUpload id="formUpload">
   <input type="file" class="input-file-ghost" (change)="onChangeFile($event.target.files)">
</form>
....
```

*`component.ts`*

```
export class UploadFileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() .....;
  @Output() filesAdded = new EventEmitter<File>();
  @ViewChild('formUpload') formUpload: ElementRef;
  ...

  constructor() { .... }

  ngOnInit() { .... }

  onChangeFile(files: File[]) { ..... }
}
```

*`Use case`*

```
<app-upload-file
        [uploadFileConfig]="...."
        (filesAdded)="....">
 </app-upload-file>

**********

formCvData: FormData = new FormData();
onFileUploaded($event) {
  const uploaded = $event;
  this.formLmData.set('.....', uploaded, uploaded.name);
}
```

Work fine when this component is used on Chrome and Mozilla browsers, but when I go on **IE 9** I have this error :

> 'FormData' is undefined

I looked in the git issues and [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) projects, I have't found anything that can solve the problem with a modern solution.

**IMPORTANT :** I am looking for a solution that does not use **jQuery** nor **Ajax**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormData is not available in IE9:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility

You will have to manually gather and encode the form data yourself.

Comment: Is there a solution using polyfiles ?